# Connection Loss Handling in AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In My application i have read all the record from the DataBase SqlServer by using REST API.But there is some problem when connection loss at intermediate execution of protected DetailsTimeTable doInBackground(String... params). Then my app closed with error Unfortunately app has stopped
Here is my Code:

```
public class Monday_Time extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private BroadcastReceiver mconn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time_table_list);
        // Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Toast.makeText(this, MainActivity.branch_static, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // registerReceiver(new NetworkBroadCast(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER));
        mconn = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
                boolean isfailOver = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
                NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

                Log.d("Connectivity", Boolean.toString(noConnectivity));
                Log.d("Reson ", reason);
                Log.d("FailOver", Boolean.toString(isfailOver));
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(mconn, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

        new AsyncDetailsTimeTable().execute(MainActivity.branch_static.trim(), MainActivity.sem_static.trim(), MainActivity.sec_static.trim(), "Monday");
    }

    public class AsyncDetailsTimeTable extends AsyncTask<String, Void, DetailsTimeTable> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Monday_Time.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loding Time Table....");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(DetailsTimeTable result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.d("POST DATA", result.getFirst());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (SSTCTimeTableTabActivity.ram == 1) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Monday_Time.this);
                builder.setMessage("Time Table is not availble....")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // do things
                            startActivity(new Intent(Monday_Time.this, com.src.sstctimetable.MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                        }
                    });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                itemsList.add("1:: " + result.getFirst());
                itemsList.add("2:: " + result.getSecond());
                itemsList.add("3:: " + result.getThird());
                itemsList.add("4:: " + result.getFourth());
                itemsList.add("5:: " + result.getFifth());
                itemsList.add("6:: " + result.getSixth());
                itemsList.add("7:: " + result.getSeventh());

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, itemsList));
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected DetailsTimeTable doInBackground(String... params) {
            DetailsTimeTable userDetail = null;
            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetTimeTableDetails(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                userDetail = parser.parseUserDetails(jsonObj);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());
            }
            return userDetail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will show NullPointerException on LogCat

Comment: doInBackground(String... params) method statement                          userDetail = parser.parseUserDetails(jsonObj);                                                                             gives NullPointerException when connection Lost at the time of fetch the data from SqlServer by using Handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    // Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());
}
```

Try to comment `Log` print. I think `e.getmessage()` throwing `NullPointerException`.